# extracting a row from a file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a CSV file, with the columns like below,

```
User     Name   Env   Role
user1    pap    dev    dev
user2    nic    uat    test
```

I need to extract a row, with respect to either the column 'Env' or 'User'. 
The script 'extract.sh' I have written is,

```
k=$2
field=$3
head -1 $1; cat $1 | awk -F "," -v k=`echo $k` -v field=`echo $field` '{ k=k;j=$field; if ( j==k )  print $0}'
```

The script is called with 3 parameters like this , **sh extract.sh username.csv dev 3**  the first parameter is csv file the second is the value and the third is column no,
the output i am getting is

```
User Name Env Role
user1 pap dev  dev
```

But I need the output like this,

```
User = user1 
Name = pap
Env = dev
Role = dev
```

Could anyone please help me in getting this ?

Comment: You're doing too much work assigning the awk variables: `-v k="$k" -v field="$field"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F, -v RS='\r\n' -v col=$3 -v val="$2" 'NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) hdr[i]=$i;next}
             $col == val {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print hdr[i], "=", $i; exit}' "$1"
User = user1
Name = pap
Env = dev
Role = dev
```

**Explanation:**

```
NR == 1      # For first row save headers in an array called hdr
$col == val  # when passed val is same as the value of column indicated by col
```

Comment: May I know how you are passing the filename parameter ?

Comment: I am not getting output and also no errors. Any idea ?

Comment: Run this awk directly from command line like this: `awk -v col=3 -v val='dev' 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) hdr[i]=$i; next} $col == val {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print hdr[i], "=", $i; exit}' file`. This gives me output attached in answer.

Comment: I have tried it as command also, but the same problem. Couldn't figure out.

Comment: That means your file is not same as shown in question. Using `cat -vte file` check whether you have DOS line ending. If yes then run `dos2unix` to convert to unix file.

Comment: I have tried to convert the file to unix using dos2unix but resulted in error "problem converting file filename.csv"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77292/discussion-between-user2112700-and-anubhava).